# Treat stochastically non-Hamiltonian perturbations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory, stochastic-processes

Let us consider a classical dynamical system whose obserbvables $A$ evolve according to the following equation of motion
\begin{align}
\dot A &= -\{H,A\}+f(q)
\end{align}
$f(q)$ is a non-Hamiltonian perturbation to an otherwise Hamiltonian system and
\begin{equation}
\ H = \frac{p^2}{2m}+V(q)
\end{equation}
I would like to systematically construct a stochastic process $\xi(t)$ which allowed me to approximate the non-Hamiltonian perturbation $f(q)$. In particular I would like to approximate the equation of the force with a stochastic equation
\begin{equation}
\dot A \approx -\{H,A\}+\xi(t)
\end{equation}
Let us define with $\langle \cdot\rangle$ thermal averages w.r.t. the stationary distribution of the unperturbed Hamiltonian $H$. I was wondering whether it would be possible to construct the moments of the noise $\langle \prod_{i=1}^n \xi(t_i) \rangle$ (and hence the noise itself) from the moments of the perturbation $\langle f^n(q)\rangle$. For example, if we considered the simplest approximation of Gaussian noise, I would be tempted to identify
\begin{equation}
\langle \xi(t)\rangle = \langle f\rangle\hspace{10mm}\langle \xi(t)\xi(t')\rangle = \langle (f-\langle f\rangle)^2\rangle\delta(t-t')
\end{equation}
I would appreciate any hint about formalism to treat this class of problems.

Comment: By any chance, do you mean $\dot{A} \approx -\{H,A\} + \xi(t)$ in your stochastic equation line? Also, could you discuss a little more why you are introducing stochasticity instead of looking for a deterministic $\xi$? Also, by moments of $f(q)$, are those averages over time?

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the error. I am ultimately interested in computing correlation function $C(t)=\langle A(0) B(t)\rangle$, where the dynamics of $B$ is written via these quasi-Hamiltonian equations of motion. Treating the perturbation stochastically may allow for a simpler evaulation of the effects of $f(q)$ on the equilibrium average in $C(t)$. Ideally, I would like to compute moments of $f(q)$ with the stationary distribution associated to the non-perturbed Hamiltonian $H$. However, any approach that points in the right direction would surely help

Comment: With the caveat that I didn't give too much thought to this (thus this being a comment rather than an answer), is Mori-Zwanzig formalism of any use here (quite often used to "project out the fast degrees of freedom in coarse graining", whereby I mean going from some deterministc system of ODEs to an SDE in a systematic way)?

Comment: I that Mori-Zwanzig is suited for Hamiltonian system. I can see whether it's also applicable to the non-Hamiltonian dynamics discussed here though